# C++ rvalue forwarding

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

According to Resharper , this here is invalid c++:

```
class IData{
    IData();
    virtual doStuff() = 0;
}
class MyData: public IData{
    MyData(MyData&& mdrv);
    doStuff() override{/*....*/};
}
class DataUser(){
    DataUser(IData& d){   //all explicits are ommitted for brevity, don't call me out on that please :)
        d.doStuff();
    }
}
int main(){
    DataUser d(MyData()); //it complains here: Binding Rvalue Reference to lvalue Reference is a non standard MSVC extension
}
```

**I cant make IData& const**, because doStuff does stuff (duh!)

What I did was this:

```
 class DataUser(){
     DataUser(IData& d){
         d.doStuff();
     }
     DataUser(IData&& d): DataUser(d){  //added this, no complains anywhere
     }
 }
```

Now my Questions are:

1. Is the first one really non standard complying c++?
2. How does the addition of my cheaty constructor change anything, and is it standards complying?
3. If neither of these are valid (which is what i fear), how could i create cheaty constructor 2.0, letting me pass a **non const** rvalue? [without templated perferct forwarding please, i want to retain my source entirely in .cpp] All IDatas have valid move constructors and assignment operators

Comment: AFAIK temporaries can only be bound to `const` references, or rvalue references.

Comment: More information [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary)

Comment: So you are saying that I'm totally relying on the MSVC extension in case 2 aswell?

Comment: @ChrisB, case 2 is fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why? Where is the difference? Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisB, read the docs linked... If it still doesn't make sense read the docs about [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)

Comment: _a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the object exists. (note: such initialization is ill-formed as of DR 1696)_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138390/discussion-between-incomputable-and-chrisb).

Comment: `DataUser d(MyData());` is the most vexing parse, to begin with

Comment: It is really darn convenient though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out due to the amazing help by @Incomputable.

It boils down to the facts that:

- Rvalue references extend the lifetime of the object that they are holding until they go out of scope
- **Const** Lvalue References do the same, but obviously cant be modified
- **Non const** Lvalue References that are initialized with rvalue ref do **NOT** extend the lifetime of the rvalue
- Due to **reference collapsing**, the delegate constructor calls the lvalue constructor, and not itself

Additional resources (provided again by @Incomputable) can be found

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) and [Here (especially the paragraph entitled Rvalue references is very good)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)

That is why

```
class DataUser(){
    DataUser(IData& d){ 
        d.doStuff();
    }
}
int main(){
    DataUser d(MyData()); //lvalue ref is initalized  with rvalue, Rvalue goes out of scope --> UB
}
```

but

```
class DataUser(){
        DataUser(IData& d){ 
            d.doStuff();
        }
        DataUser(IData&& d): DataUser(d){ //the rvalues lifetime is extended until the constructor exits and d goes out of scope
        }
    }
    int main(){
        DataUser d(MyData()); //this works like a charm and is perfectly legal
    }
```

Comment: also you might like to know that you are calling doStuff() twice for an rvalue

Comment: ah thanks for the heads up! copy paste error :) it wouldn't even compile this way as c++ only supports delegat constructors. editing now.